# MongoDB Installation where SSL isn't available

Tags: mongodb, ssl, centos6

On one server that has MongoDB v3.0.8 installed, if I run following command it shows a bunch of "SSL options" that can be passed in as arguments when starting the mongod server.

```
    mongod --help
```

It shows arguments like the following:

```
    --sslMode
    --sslPEMKeyFile
    --sslCAFile
    --sslCRLFile
```

On another server that MongoDB v3.0.8 installed, if I run that same help command to see which options can be passed in to start the mongod server, it does not show these same "SSL options".  Neither of these MongoDB installations appear to be enterprise edition.  Why would one show these "SSL options" and the other installation not?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Per the MongoDB documentation, you must have SSL libraries installed alongside your MongoDB distribution. It is likely that one is missing those libraries. Please see the [configuring SSL documentation](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/tutorial/configure-ssl/) as well as the documentation for your distribution.

Comment: Thank you for the response.  I was able to download the Github source for MongoDB and build it with the ssl option.  Thank you for the direction.